# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. in flutter app

Tags: flutter

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzy0v.png)
I want to add a background image png. but it gives me>>> The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. how can I FIX THIS ERROR

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          body: Column(
              children: <Widget>\[
          Expanded(
          child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.4,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/girl.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,

            ),
          ),
              
        ),
      flex: 2,
          ),
  ]
    ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not closing  your appbar  curcular braces

Comment: yeah got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try below code you have wrote wrong code :

Refer **`Scaffold`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'App Bar',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      "https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            flex: 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close your **AppBar** Widget before starting body.
`body` is an attribute of `Scaffold` tree but you put it in `AppBar`

Look below:

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ), // Here were your problem
          body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
          child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.4,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/girl.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,

            ),
          ),
              
        ),
      flex: 2,
          ),
  ]
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Devindi your welcome. do check mark my answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually missing your `AppBar` circular closing  braces

```
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```